# Post login form in Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, http-post

I want to login to an external site (not my own) using Sencha Touch.

Here's some of my code:

**Login controller**

```
Ext.define('Myapp.controller.Login', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

config: {
    refs: {
       loginForm: '#login-form'  
    },
    control: {
       '#login-button': {
          tap: 'onLoginHandler'
       } 
    }
},

onLoginHandler: function() {
  var form = this.getLoginForm();
  Ext.Ajax.request({
      url: 'https://www.site.com/login.html',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      method: 'POST',
      params: form.getValues(),
      callback: function(options, success, response){
        console.log(options);
        console.log(response);
      }
  });
}
});
```

**Login view**

```
Ext.define('Myapp.view.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias:  'widget.loginview',
    xtype: 'loginform',
    id: 'login-form',
    requires: [
        'Ext.form.FieldSet'
    ],

    config: {
        title: 'Log in',
        iconCls: 'user',
        html: 'Login View',
        method: 'POST',
        items: [ 
            {
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: 'Log in',
                items: [ 
                    bunch of fields
                ]
            },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Login',
            ui: 'action',
            id: 'login-button'

        } 
    ]
}
});
```

The result i see in my browser debugger is not what I'm expecting:

```
Request URL:https://www.site.com/login.html?_dc=1375705385394
Request Headers
    Access-Control-Request-Headers:origin, x-requested-with, content-type
    Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
    Origin:http://localhost
    Referer:http://localhost/~me/non/
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36
Query String Parameters URL encoded
    _dc:1375705385394
```

The form data isn't even there. But it shows up in the console.log from "console.log(response)" (see controller) so it should be sent

The request module for node seems works as I want it to..

```
var request = require('request');
var form = require('form-data');
var r = request.post('https://www.site.com/login.html', function(err, resp, body){

});

var frm = r.form();
frm.append(...// same fields as in my View, values are hardcoded for testing
```

The difference between these two is that the form is appended after the request...?

Here's the headers when i login manually:

```
Request URL:https://www.site.com/login.html
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Request Headers
    Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/ *;q=0.8
    Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,sv;q=0.6
    Cache-Control:max-age=0
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:53
    Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Cookie:NOW=4b21bf97818dd91f28732aec2b12344e28ac4aef; TUX-COOKIE=R2414511234; /=; /firsttimeload=0; s_cc=true; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D
    Host:www.site.com
    Origin:https://www.site.com
    Referer:https://www.site.com/
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36
Form Data URL encoded
    ...my secret form data shows up here
Response Headersview source
    Connection:Keep-Alive
    Content-Encoding:gzip
    Content-Length:184
    Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
    Date:Mon, 05 Aug 2013 12:57:09 GMT
    Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
    Location:../redirect/location
    Server:Apache
    Set-Cookie:TUX-COOKIE=R2414511234; path=/
    Set-Cookie:NOW=none; path=/; expires=Fri, 08-Aug-2003 12:57:09 GMT; secure
    Set-Cookie:NOW=e555573f3e21a1f008f4be34c7c61234b1014b6; path=/; secure
    Vary:Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
```

Any thoughts or ideas are welcome! THANKS!

Comment: Doesn't POST fail to external sites due to the same-origin policy? If you're testing in Chrome you have to enable file:/// urls to access remote hosts from AJAX.

Comment: Does this mean that in order to do this i need to use some kind of iframe hack or maybe make the request through node or something else (is that possbile)?

The plan is to make a super simple smartphone app that just parses and renders a website that i often use into a smartphone friendly and possibly better version of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordinarily how I would take care of this problem is create a proxy service on my local server using NodeJS or PHP. This process would allow me to submit my ajax request to the same-origin and then I'd use a backend post/fetch to interact with the third party service.

In addition to the added security provided by complying with the same-origin policy; this has a couple of extra benefits. Your Ext app can do a lot less hand wrangling and you are able to support more than one service endpoint in your proxy. If the service changes you'll have server code that you can test without a UI and this can simplify debugging.

It may be possible to submit your request using JSONP but that would be highly ill-advised if you're transmitting login credentials.